# How to Find Specific Nearby Locations in android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have requirement in my project that is finding nearby movie theaters upto certain radius from the user present location then i want to show these finding location in the google map. I have seen some posts here but i did not get the clarity on this. Is there any direct API calls to get the nearest specific places or any other way to find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of places surrounding user's current location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181812/get-list-of-places-surrounding-users-current-location)

Answer (score 2):

[Get list of places surrounding user's current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181812/get-list-of-places-surrounding-users-current-location/6201892#6201892)