# finding nearby locations

Tags: android, location

How to get the locations nearby me? I've got a latitude and location. Based on this, I want to get nearest locations.

How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of places surrounding user's current location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181812/get-list-of-places-surrounding-users-current-location)

Answer (score 2):

I assume by 'locations' you mean places/venues/stores/etc?

There are several Location Based Services that provide APIs to retrieve lists of nearby venues.

- SimpleGeo:
  https://simplegeo.com/products/places/
- Gowalla: http://gowalla.com/api/docs
- Foursquare: http://foursquare.com/apps/

If you are using Gowalla, there's http://code.google.com/p/gowalla-java/ which should get you up and running quickly to access nearby places.

Answer (score 2):

[Get list of places surrounding user's current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181812/get-list-of-places-surrounding-users-current-location)

Comment: @JT703 Thanks for your help in improving this question! This should be a comment though. Keep writing good questions and answers, and you'll be able to formally cast close votes.

Comment: I put it as an answer, because the answer to this question is in that link. I asked that question after reading this one, and found the (an) answer a little afterwards.

What does "formally cast close votes" mean? :)

Comment: @JT703 Questions can be closed, thereby function as pointers to the generic one - on point in duplicating effort across multiple questions. With 250 points, you'll the close count under each question (like `link|edit|close (1)|flag`), and with 3000 points, you'll be able to vote for close yourself. Close reasons are "duplicate", "spam", "off topic" etc.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.  There is another one similar to this that I found in my search. I did the same thing there that I did here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037718/how-to-find-specific-nearby-locations-in-android/6214777#6214777

Comment: Yes, I understand that mine actually was the duplicate. But I seriously couldn't find any good answers, and I thought maybe it was because people we not being clear. Plus the upvotes are for questions that show research effort, which I felt I needed to show, especially because of the number of similar questions already in existence.

Comment: @JT703 Yeah, you're right, your question shows research effort, but bear in mind that answers - such as your excellent one ("Google Places API") make existing questions appear on the frontpage, too.